# How can I recreate a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm using a widget called SwipeRefreshLayout, to refresh my fragment when someone pushes the view.

To recreate the activity I have to use:

```
SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

public static LobbyFragment newInstance() {
    return new LobbyFragment();
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lobby, container, false);


    receiver = new MySQLReceiver();

    rlLoading = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.rlLoading);
    gvLobby = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gvLobby);

    updateList();

    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.mSwipeRefreshLayout);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.pDarkGreen, R.color.pDarskSlowGreen, R.color.pLightGreen, R.color.pFullLightGreen);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {

            getActivity().recreate();
        }


    });


    return view;

}
```

But I don't want to recreate the full activity that contains the view pager, I would like to recreate the fragment. How can I do that?

Comment: share your fragment creation code

Comment: is it because you want to update your data list inside the fragment?

Comment: Yea, I'm using a gridview and I would like to update that gridview

Comment: When your activity is recreated, go directly to the fragment which you like by using viewpager.setCurrentItem(FRAGMENT_POSITION);

Comment: @RúbenDias check my answer

Comment: Can you describe the user interaction with your app? What can the user do and how should the app respond? It would help if you also provide screenshots and or mockups.

Comment: instead of recreating fragment call update list

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use :

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, LobbyFragment.newInstance()).commit();
```

To recreate your fragment

Note:`getSupportFragmentManager()` is if you are using support fragment and AppCompatActivity , if you are using framework fragment class you need to use `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: I think `LobbyFragment.newInstance()` is missing a `class` before the newInstance, otherwise thanks for the answer

Comment: @Rick77 that is method call so no it aint missing a class

Comment: right, my bad: I missed that part in the question, and I thought your intention was LobbyFragment.class.newInstance().

Comment: Just use new LobbyFragment()

Comment: Just use new LobbyFragment()

Answer (score 23):

I'm using  `.detach()`  and  `.attach()`  for recreating the fragment.

**ATTACH**

> Re-attach a fragment after it had previously been deatched from the UI with detach(Fragment). This causes its view hierarchy to be re-created, attached to the UI, and displayed.

**DETACH**

> Detach the given fragment from the UI. This is the same state as when it is put on the back stack: the fragment is removed from the UI, however its state is still being actively managed by the fragment manager. When going into this state its view hierarchy is destroyed.

**HOW I USE IT**

```
getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .detach(LobbyFragment.this)
        .attach(LobbyFragment.this)
        .commit();
```

Comment: This worked for me, the first answer didn't. Thanks!

Comment: where should i call this ??

Comment: @pavel Where you need to recreate the fragment

Comment: For me, instead of attach detach i did .replace(R.id.fragment_container, new WhateverFragment() ).addToBackstack(null).commit();

Comment: This method doesn't work for Android SDK 23, Android Studio even provides a relevant warning:
**Calling detach() and attach() in the same FragmentTransaction is a no-op, meaning it does not recreate the Fragment's view. If you would like the view to be recreated, separate these operations into separate transactions.**

I've tested both approaches and only the following worked for me:
```getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(LobbyFragment.this).commit();```
```getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().attach(LobbyFragment.this).commit();```

Comment: @KubaK Could you please share which android-provided documentation pages you referred to? So that I can update my answer for the better.

Comment: @G.Ciardini Here you go: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions#attach-detach
Apparently to make sure the transaction is commited, `executePendingOperations()` call is also needed between those lines I added.

Comment: @KubaK, Thank you for your comment, that really did the whole trick

Answer (score 17):

If you're using Navigation Component, you can use this:

```
findNavController().navigate(
    R.id.current_dest,
    arguments,
    NavOptions.Builder()
        .setPopUpTo(R.id.current_dest, true)
        .build()
)
```

This lets NavController pop up the current fragment and then navigate to itself. You get a new Fragment and fragment ViewModel also gets recreated.

Comment: Worked it for me. Greatest !!!

Answer (score 6):

**For Kotlin Lover**

if you want to recreate fragment you should dettach() fragment then attach() fragment

please follow this step

**setp : 1** , first create a method recreateFragment() on your activity class

```
fun recreateFragment(fragment : Fragment){
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N){
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().detach(fragment).commitNow()
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().attach(fragment).commitNow()
    }else{
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().detach(fragment).attach(fragment).commitNow()
    }
}
```

**step : 2** , then call this method on your fragment to recreate this fragment

suppose A Button click then recreate this fragment

```
    button.setOnClickListener {
        (activity as yourActivity).recreateFragment(this)
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to refresh from activity then use:

```java
getSupportfragmentmanager()
  .begintransaction
  .detach(fragment)
  .attach(fragment)
  .addtobackstack(null)
  .commit();
```

and if you are in fragment already then use:

```java
public class MyDetailFragment extends Fragment {
  ....
  private void refreshFragment(){
    getFragmentManager()
      .beginTransaction()
      .detach(this)
      .attach(this)
      .addToBackStack(null)
      .commit();
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

who use Navigation Component !! :
just put a self destination .

```
<action
   android:id="@+id/action_piecesReferenceCount_self"
   app:destination="@id/piecesReferenceCount" />
```

```
Navigation.findNavController(myview).navigate(R.id.action_piecesReferenceCount_self);
```

Comment: The issue with this is any arguments passed to the fragment will become null

Answer (score 1):

Using the method from Ciardini I got errors sometimes. This works always:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
    ft.setReorderingAllowed(false);
}

ft.detach(this).attach(this).commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a Kotlin extension function:

```
/**
 * Recreate a fragment without recreating any associated fragment view model. This is useful if initially some work needs
 * to be done to set up the data for a fragment. At the start the layout shows a "working" fragment state. When the work completes
 * the fragment view model is set to indicate the data is available, and this triggers a different layout to be inflated.
 *
 * This causes [Fragment.onDestroy] followed by [Fragment.onViewCreated] to be called (but not [Fragment.onCreate]).
 *
 * For background see  [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39296873/how-can-i-recreate-a-fragment)
 */
fun Fragment.recreateFragment() {
    val fragment = this
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction().detach(fragment).commitNow()
        parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction().attach(fragment).commitNow()
    } else {
        parentFragmentManager.beginTransaction().detach(fragment).attach(fragment).commitNow()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use 2 transactions for the fragment to reload its content list:

```
FragmentTransaction ftr = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ftr.detach(localCurrentPrimaryItem)
                        .commit();

FragmentTransaction ftr2 = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ftr2.attach(localCurrentPrimaryItem)
                        .commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a fragment that needed to be recreated when I clicked on a button, what I did was the following in the onCreateView of the fragment (MyFragmentClass) class:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    Button annuler = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonAnnulerCreation);
    annuler.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                getParentFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentLayout, new MyFragmentClass()).commit();
            }
        }); }
```

Answer (score 0):

As `getFragmentManager()` is deprecated , this way in side a fragment can be useful.

```
FragmentManager manager = this.getParentFragmentManager();

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                manager.beginTransaction().detach(this).commitNow();
                manager.beginTransaction().attach(this).commitNow();
            } else {
                manager.beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commitNow();
            }
```